# Matlab minimization with fminsearch and parametrized function

Tags: matlab, math

I am writing a program in Matlab and I have a function defined this way.

```
sum (i=1...100) (a*x(i) + b*y(i) + c)
```

`x` and `y` are known, while a, b and c are not: I need to find values for them such that the total value of the function is minimized. There is no additional constraint for the problem.

I thought of using fminsearch to solve this minimization problem, but from Mathworks I get that functions which are suitable inputs for fminsearch are defined like this (an example):

```
square = @(x) x.^2
```

So in my case I could use a vector `p=[a, b, c]` as the value to minimize, but then I don't know how to define the remaining part of the function. As you can see the number of possible values for the index i is huge, so I cannot simply sum everything together explicitly, but I need to represent the summation in some way. If I write the function somewhere else then I am forced to use symbolic calculus for a, b and c (declaring them with syms) and I'm not sure fminsearch would accept that.

What can I do? Of course if fminsearch turns out to be unfeasible for my situation I accept links to use something else.

Comment: You want to minimize the pure sum, subject to NO constraints? There is no minimum. My guess is you have a different problem. So why not tell us just a bit more, rather than confusing us?

Comment: a = b = c = -inf. done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general solution is to use `x` and `y` in the definition of the objective function:

```
>> objfun = @(p) sum( p(1).*x + p(2).*y + p(3) );
>> optp = fminsearch( objfun, po, ... );
```

Comment: Great, so you can use sum() directly. Thanks a lot :)